# Implementing 1D array of characters (basically string) using POINTERS in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I can not understand why whole "abcde" is not printed from my code, can you help please ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int L,i,j;
    char *p;
    scanf("%d",&L);
    p=(char *)malloc(L+1);
    for(i=0;i<L;i++)
     scanf("%c",p+i);
    *(p+i)='\0';
    for(j=0;j<L;j++)
     printf("%c",*(p+j));
}
```

output : https://ibb.co/jv2HnR

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code. Copy-paste is simple.

Comment: Obviously the "newline" character is what went wrong.

Comment: *(p+1) should be printing b, but it prints a - i dont understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your second input of reading string length, there's a newline character left in the input stream, which is read by the upcoming `scanf()` call. So after your inner loop of reading the string character-by-character, you actually got a string like this:

```
{'\n', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};
```

So your printing statement does this equivalently:

```
printf("\nabcd");
```

You can skip the whitespaces by inserting a space before the `scanf()` format string:

```
for (j = 0; j < L; j++)
    scanf(" %c", p+j);
//         ^
```

In this way you'll get your desired output.